# Swap rows in gnumeric

Tags: spreadsheet, gnumeric

Is there any convenient way to swap two rows in gnumeric? Currently I'm doing it the hard way: insert an empty row, move rows, and remove empty row. I hope that there is a better way...

Comment: Which operating system and what version of gnumeric?

Comment: @harrymc I don't know about the OP, I'm running xubuntu 14.04 64 bit, gnumeric version 1.12.9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Select both rows (using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key or by dragging the mouse - don't use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key)
- Copy
- Right-click → **Paste Special**
- In **Region operation**, choose **Flip Vertically**

[image: Swapping 2 rows in Gnumeric]

Comment: how to properly select rows? http://i.imgur.com/h98CK3c.png

Comment: @Fischer, I pressed **Shift** then clicked on the row numbers.

Comment: @Fischer, I forgot to mention that I have gnumeric-1.12.17-1.fc20.x86_64 (Fedora 20).

Comment: Yes, to select the full rows you have to click on the row numbers (on the left), and not on the cells. ṧнʊß's animation accurately reflects it (remember you have to click on the shift key if you click on the rows, as he did).

Comment: I saw now your screenshot. You likely pressed the **ctrl** key, which makes multiple ranges, instead of the **shift** key, which extends a single range. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu than you, i've never knew that you can use animated gif in your answer. could you tell me how did you create it? if it's easy, i might do it all the time in my future posts, easier than capturing multiple screenshots

Comment: For screencasting see [How to create animated GIF images of a screencast?](http://askubuntu.com/q/107726/74792) on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu thanks again, I have an unrelated question, I was considering going for fedora since I like centos servers. Just a small question, since the life cycle of fedora is so short, how smooth is upgrading to new version? on ubuntu it's usually a mess

Comment: I forgot to mention that from all the answer given on Ask Ubuntu, I used the [byzanz-record-window](http://askubuntu.com/a/201018/74792) script and [gifsicle](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast#comment345858_107735) to optimize (recompress) it.

Comment: @Fischer, I don't upgrade Fedora, I just install the new version. Though I used [FedUp](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp) once to upgrade from Fedora 18 to 19 and it worked fine for me, but it had some [hiccups](https://plus.google.com/111049168280159033135/posts/5Y2hPoKFDoy) for Greg Kroah-Hartman. I'd also like to add that Fedora Next has Server product with a longer [lifecycle](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Server/Proposals/Server_Lifecycle) of eighteen months.

Comment: @ValmikyArquissandas Thanks, that's a nice solution! And it's possible to swap colums like this too. Too bad that gnumeric doesn't support copy for multiple ranges.